# Having trouble hiding and showing a div using PHP+Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

User submits their email address, email is checked if it's valid and not in the database..

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the form to hide and the thank you div to show, once the form has been submitted successfully. It currently replaces the email textbox with "Thank you!" text which I don't want.

What must be changed or added so the form is hidden (after it passes error/validation checks) and the thank you div is shown?

Thank you!!

**Index.php**

```
<?php

require "includes/connect.php";

$msg = '';

if($_POST['email']){

    // Requested with AJAX:
    $ajax = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']  == 'XMLHttpRequest');

    try{
        if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Invalid Email!');
        }

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails
                        SET email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");

        if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){
            throw new Exception('You are already on the notification list.');
        }

        if($ajax){
            die('{"status":1}');
        }

        $msg = "Thank you!";

    }
    catch (Exception $e){

        if($ajax){
            die(json_encode(array('error'=>$e->getMessage())));
        }

        $msg = $e->getMessage();        
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Notify me test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="launch">

    <h1>Notify</h1>

    <h2>Notify me</h2>

    <form id="form" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $msg?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
    </form>

    <div style="display:none" id="thankyou">
    Thank you!
    </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Binding event listeners for the form on document ready

    $('#email').defaultText('Enter your Email Address');

    // 'working' prevents multiple submissions
    var working = false;

    $('#page form').submit(function(){

        if(working){
            return false;
        }
        working = true;

        $.post("./index.php",{email:$('#email').val()},function(r){
            if(r.error){
                $('#email').val(r.error);
            }
            else $('#email').val('Thank you!');

            working = false;
        },'json');

        return false;
    });
});

// A custom jQuery method for placeholder text:

$.fn.defaultText = function(value){

    var element = this.eq(0);
    element.data('defaultText',value);

    element.focus(function(){
        if(element.val() == value){
            element.val('').removeClass('defaultText');
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if(element.val() == '' || element.val() == value){
            element.addClass('defaultText').val(value);
        }
    });

    return element.blur();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code in there at all that even attempts to do anything like hiding the form and showing that "thankyou" div. Also, I **do** see code that **explicitly** sets the input field value to "Thank you".

Comment: @Pointy: I attempted to replace the line of setting the textbox id "email" with the hide/show function but it errors, even as suggested below, it still errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you do this if you dont want to replace input with thank you text?

```
else $('#email').val('Thank you!');
```

instead do 
`else {
    $("#form").hide();
    $("#thankyou").show();
}`

Comment: @Eugene msc: It was from a tutorial :) just wanted to customise. Thanks for the help, but it errors with: Fatal error: Call to undefined function hide() in /home/..../index.php on line 28

Comment: do you have anything on your page that jquery might conflict with? try jQuery("#form").hide();jQuery("#thankyou").show();

Comment: @Eugene msc: Still the same error - Fatal error: Call to undefined function hide(). The above code in my original post os all the code there is..

Comment: @Eugene msc: Very strange.. the error no longer appears, however the hide/show doesn't occur. Rather, the "thank you!" text is displayed in the textbox.

Comment: yeah that is strange. if you use firebug you can set brakpoint at that line and look what $("#form") object looks like and see what functions it has

Comment: @Eugene msc: what's stranger is that even when I remove else $('#email').val('Thank you!');  and replace with else { }, it still displays the thank you text in the textbox. Does this help? I think it's grabbing it from PHP at the top of the index file. I'll run firebug.. in the meantime if you work it out please let me know. Thanks

Comment: i don't think it's possible. the only piece of code that sets text into textbox is $('#email').val('Thank you!'); it's probably caching or something.

Comment: @Eugene msc: I've cleared cache, tested firebug, nothing wrong. I don't get it :/ If you run it on your end does it work correctly?

Comment: @Eugene msc: If I change $msg = "Thank you!"; at the top of index.php to $msg = "Thank you test!"; it displays the new message. Is there something I can edit in that area? (at the top of index.php)

Comment: @jeremycollins i think i found the problem it's $('#page form') there is no #page element, so submit just reload the page with email parameter posted, and javascript doesn't work at all. try changing it to $("#form")

Comment: @Eugene msc: GENIUS!! Thank you sooooo much!!

Comment: @Eugene msc: One more thing, sorry - do you know how I can fade in and then fade out, both slowly?

Comment: $("#form").fadeOut('slow') or $("#form").hide('slow') same for fadeIn and show